# Custom ifilter for sqlserver works only for first file

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search, ifilter, filetable

I created a custom ifilter for a new extension (.abc).
When I installed it in operative system, the search works well.
When I tried to use it in sqlserver 2012 on a full text index on a filetable table, I saw that only one file was indexed correctly.
I tried to debug the indexing task attaching the debug at fdhost.exe. I saw that my class was instantiated and destroyed exactly as many times as the files .abc in the table, but only the first time I saw calls to IPersistFile::Load, IFilter::Init, IFilter:GetChunk, IFilter::GetText, next time only constructor and destructor was call on my class.
Also, in next time, after call to constructor I see in output window of visual studio 2012 an exception:
*First-chance exception at 0x000007fefd44a49d in fdhost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CNLBaseException at memory location 0x01022c30.*

I haven't found any documentation on this error and on behaviour of fdhost in order to understand where the error is.

Thank you for answer.
Luigi